# How to launch lottie player animation on click button in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, lottie

I have a lottie animation json file called **congratulations.json**. I have included the path of the file inside **src** in **lottie player tag** like this:

```html
<lottie-player
  class="justify-content-center"
  src="../../../congratulations.json"
  background="transparent"
  speed="1"
  style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
  loop
  controls
  autoplay
></lottie-player>
```

I want to launch this lottie player animation on click over a button in vue.js.

I have coded like this:

```html
<div class="justify-content-center">
  <button v-on:click="cong" class="btn">
    animation
  </button>
</div>

methods: {
  cong() {
    <lottie-player
      class="justify-content-center"
      src="../../../congratulations.json"
      background="transparent"
      speed="1"
      style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
      loop
      controls
      autoplay
    ></lottie-player>;
  },
}
```

But its not working. Do I need to install any addons/extensions or my code is incorrect ?

Comment: try adding a telda `~` before the path so webpack would understand that this is a path

Comment: Please kindly show me where to include telda. Thats not clear to me.

Comment: nvm, looked it up and it seems to be working with CSS only, it would've been `src="~../../../congratulations.json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't seem like the correct way to do what you want in Vue. I assume you want to show the lottie player when the button is clicked. If so, here is one way to do it:

You can have a boolean variable in the `data` of the component, e.g. `showPlayer` which will be initially set to `false`. Then, you can delete the `cong` method and have something like this:

```
<div class="justify-content-center">
    <button v-on:click="showPlayer = true" class="btn">
      animation
    </button>
    <lottie-player
            v-if="showPlayer"
            class="justify-content-center"
            src="**../../../congratulations.json**"
            background="transparent"
            speed="1"
            style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
            loop
            controls
            autoplay
    ></lottie-player>
</div>
```

Of course, this is only the template code. You need to have the boolean variable in the component's `data`. The lottie-player tag's attributes should also be correct in order for this to work.

Comment: Here showPlayer is a variable. I ts not a function. So why you included it in v-on:click=" "

Comment: It is a variable indeed. However, you can write one-line JS expressions inside v-on (and other Vue directives such as v-bind and v-if) as wekk, So I'm writing the expression to set showPlayer to true inside v-on (it's a simple thing to do, but you can enclose it in a method if you really want to).

Comment: Worked.........finally